# Dimensionally, how does this have units of velocity: $2 q I/(m c^2)$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, dimensional-analysis, units

I'm reading through a paper about charged particle trajectories in non-uniform magnetic fields ([*Drift velocity of charged particles in magnetic fields and its relation to the direction of the source current*, Essén & Normark](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjd/e2016-70425-9)) They set up a characteristic velocity (eq. 43):

> The quantity
>
> $v_0 ≡\frac{2qI}{m c^2}$
>
> of dimension velocity, represents a characteristic velocity of the
> system.

where $q$ is an electric charge, $I$ is electrical current, $m$ is mass, and $c$ is the speed of light.

How does this have units of velocity? When I break it down I get units of
coulombs^2 s kg^-1 m^-2

Is there a missing electrical constant? Am I using the wrong unit system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are most likely working in one of the systems of units (such as Gaussian or Heaviside-Lorentz) where factors of $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ do not appear. For instance, in Gaussian units, Coulomb's law is given by: $$F=\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r^2}$$

from which you can include that $\text{charge}^2$ has dimension $\rm N\, m^2$, and indeed it follows from there that $ \frac{2qI}{mc^2}$ has dimension velocity.

Comment: Wait hold on, why these $μ_0$ and $ε_0$ are not there in this equation of force without them how can you equate both the quantities? Without the constant the unit will become c²/m² which is not Newton just put a proportionality sign. If not then give the exact reason why you merely equated that.

Comment: @TejasDahake In Gaussian units, the unit of charge is statcoulomb, not coulomb. As a unit of charge, a statcoulomb is what you get if you set $\epsilon_0=1/4\pi$.

Answer (score -3):

Answer by yourself the question you have asked.

I will provide you the algorithm:

Suppose we have an equation/formula : A = B + CD/2

Here A, B, C, D are physical quantities with appropriate dimensions. Now if A should be dimensionally correct then the terms B and CD/2 should have the same dimensions as of A.

A few things you should keep in mind while using dimensional analysis, which are as follows:

Sometimes more than 1 physical quantity have same dimensional formula. Ex: Workdone and Energy have the same dimensional formula. Torque and Angular Momentum also have same dimensional formula.

Dimensional analysis is not the most profound way of checking correctness of equation. Ex: Newton's equation of motion sound good dimensionally but don't possess symmetry accordance to Lorentz Transformation. On the other hand Maxwell's equation are correct dimensionally as well as possess symmetry.

So, a dimensionally right formula may or may not be symmetric but a dimensionally wrong equation will never possess symmetry.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear C A Tushar Anand Naidu. Welcome to Phys.SE. It is often frown upon to post nearly identical [answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/689154/2451) to similar posts.

Comment: Once again, torque and angular momentum do not have same units.