# How can this dimensional analysis of cooling rate account for a fixed ice cube volume

Tags: dimensional-analysis, ice, cooling

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem#Cooling_a_drink_with_ice_cubes) describes an analysis of the dependence of the cooling rate of an ice cube in water on the cube edge length, $L$. It claims that Buckingham's $\pi$ theorem predicts a cooling time proportional to $L^2$ (i.e. prorportional to the surface area).

The accompanying physical explanation predicts a cooling time proportional to $L$ *for a fixed volume* (since the surface area itself varies as $1/L$ if $V$ is held constant.)

My question is: the Buckingham's $\pi$ approach fails to reproduce the physical result because it doesn't know about holding the volume constant: how (if at all) can the dimensional analysis be modified to account for fixed $V$ in the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You've completely misunderstood Wikipedia's point here: it is dimensional analysis that is correct and "physical", and not the $T\propto L$ guess they summarize in the first few sentences. While the cubes' total surface area scales as $1/L$, that's only a naive argument for a cooling time exactly proportional to $L$. For one thing, heat also takes longer to travel to the centre of a larger ice cube.

Comment: I disagree – the dimensional analysis takes account of the length-scale dependence as both volume and surface area change. The physical problem as stated requires the volume to be fixed, so given that constraint the dimensional analysis is wrong.

Comment: @mitte No, the DA gets this right. Let me spell out why I mention the transfer time through the cube. it's not just that with larger cubes fewer ice molecules can steal heat at any one moment; it's that that heat needs to move inward for them to receive more, but the time this takes is proportional to $L$. The advantage of dimensional analysis over the opening attempt at deducing the time-$L$ relation is it provides a sanity check against forgetting other power-law factors such as that.

Comment: I'm not convinced by this: on the one hand dimensional analysis justifies a factor of $L$ by the need for heat to flow inwards into the ice cube but on the other, temperature (difference) doesn't appear at all in the cooling time predicted by the same dimensional analysis.

Comment: @mitte _Of course it doesn't_. We should in general expect the time to depend on the initial temperature $T_i$ and the desired final temperature $T_f$, and there's no reason to assume this would make the result a heterogeneous polynomial in these two temperatures. If DA says the temperature dimension is $0$, $c$ is likely a function (we can't say which one!) of the dimensionless quantity $T_i/T_f$ (when both temperatures are zeroed at absolute zero, e.g. on the Kelvin scale).

Comment: I take your point, but it isn't obvious (at least to me) that the rate should depend on the ratio of the temperatures and not their difference. I have acquired some different size ice cube moulds now and I will do the experiment and report back when I can.

Comment: @mitte I wish you well with your experiment. It's hard to distinguish $T_i-T_f$ effects from e.g. $\ln(T_i/T_f)\approx T_i/T_f-1$ effects when the absolute temperature change is as small as it likely will be in your experiment, but you'll find the $L$ vs $L^2$ issue easier to test.

Answer (score -2):

Answer by yourself the question you have asked.

I will provide you the algorithm:

Suppose we have an equation/formula : A = B + CD/2

Here A, B, C, D are physical quantities with appropriate dimensions. Now if A should be dimensionally correct then the terms B and CD/2 should have the same dimensions as of A.

A few things you should keep in mind while using dimensional analysis, which are as follows:

Sometimes more than 1 physical quantity have same dimensional formula. Ex: Workdone and Energy have the same dimensional formula. Torque and Energy also have same dimensional formula.

Dimensional analysis is not the most profound way of checking correctness of equation. Ex: Newton's equation of motion sound good dimensionally but don't possess symmetry accordance to Lorentz Transformation. On the other hand Maxwell's equation are correct dimensionally as well as possess symmetry.

So, a dimensionally right formula may or may not be symmetric but a dimensionally wrong equation will never possess symmetry.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear C A Tushar Anand Naidu. Welcome to Phys.SE. It is often frown upon to post nearly identical [answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/688972/2451) to similar posts.